# tree view Entity Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I learn about making a tree view model etc , in this purpose I  am making the following example

Model Tree.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace TreeTry1.Models
{
    public class Tree
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int? Parent_Id { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Parent_Id")]
        public virtual ICollection<Tree> Group { get; set; }
    }
}
Controller:

   public ViewResult Show()
        {
            var roots = db.Tree.Where(r => r.Parent_Id == null);
            return View(roots);
        }
```

View

```
@model IEnumerable<TreeTry1.Models.Tree>
@{
    Layout = null;
}

@foreach(var item in Model){
    <li>
        @item.Name
        @if (item.Group.Count > 0)
        {
            <ul>
                @{Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Tree/TreeItem.cshtml", item.Group);}
            </ul>
        }
    </li>
}
```

Partial View

```
@model IEnumerable<TreeTry1.Models.Tree>
<ul>
    @Html.Partial("~/Views/Tree/TreeItem.cshtml")
</ul>
```

For now I recive error:

Error 1 The name 'db' does not exist in the current context

I thought that by making those classes (up) it will automatically create a database and entitiy models for that? If not then what should I do?
Do I need SQL Server for that? Or can I do it with MDF Database?

Thanks in advance for answers

Comment: You should read the Entity Framework documentation. Specifically, the "Getting Started" topic. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ee712907.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YES you need a SqlServer database for that... EntityFramework is just an access layer to the underlying DB, it does not provide DB functionality by itself.

And regarding your "db not found" problem, the answer is quite obvious: where in your code did you define the variable `db`? no where. Visual Studio can generate the DatabaseContext class for you using database first, model first or code first. After that you'll initialize that instance in your controller like:

```
DatabaseContext db = new DatabaseContext();
```

Now the compiler knows what `db` is referring to!